# Разный IL для инициализации свойств со значениями

Tags: c#

Рассматриваю в Linqpad'е IL-код простенького итератора:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new A();
    a.Skip(2).Take(5).Dump();
}

public class A : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new B();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class B : IEnumerator<int>
{
    public int Current
    {
        get
        {
            return 123;
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current { get { return this.Current; } }

    public void Dispose() {}

    public bool MoveNext() { return true; }

    public void Reset() {}
}
```

Любопытно сравнение кода, если воспользоваться новой возможностью c# 6 [Инициализация свойств со значениями](https://habrahabr.ru/post/249555/) и заменить:

```
    public int Current
    {
        get
        {
            return 123;
        }
    }
```

на:

```
   public int Current => 123;
```

Вот что будет в IL для первого случая:

```
B.get_Current:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s    7B 
IL_0003:  stloc.0     
IL_0004:  br.s        IL_0006
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  ret
```

и второго:

```
B.get_Current:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s    7B 
IL_0002:  ret
```

Обычно новые фичи языка утяжеляют конструкции, но тут обратный случай: код чище и быстрее.

Я не понимаю, что помешало комплятору в первом случае выкинуть явно лишние команды. В обоих случаях Current – свойство get-only, простая константа.

При этом если рассматривать классическую замену, то происходят абсолютно аналогичные вещи.

Для

```
void Main()
{
    var abc = new Abc {};
}

public class Abc
{
    private int _id = 123; // backing field
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
}
```

будет сгенерирован такой код:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Abc..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // abc
IL_0007:  ret         

Abc.get_Id:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldfld       UserQuery+Abc._id
IL_0007:  stloc.0     
IL_0008:  br.s        IL_000A
IL_000A:  ldloc.0     
IL_000B:  ret         

Abc.set_Id:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldarg.1     
IL_0003:  stfld       UserQuery+Abc._id
IL_0008:  ret         

Abc..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s    7B 
IL_0003:  stfld       UserQuery+Abc._id
IL_0008:  ldarg.0     
IL_0009:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  ret
```

А для

```
    public int Id { get; set; } = 123;
```

оптимизированный:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Abc..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // abc
IL_0007:  ret         

Abc.get_Id:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+Abc.<Id>k__BackingField
IL_0006:  ret         

Abc.set_Id:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery+Abc.<Id>k__BackingField
IL_0007:  ret         

Abc..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s    7B 
IL_0003:  stfld       UserQuery+Abc.<Id>k__BackingField
IL_0008:  ldarg.0     
IL_0009:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  ret
```

Вообще, что делает соптимизированный участок кода, какую роль он выполняет в старой версии кода?

Выигрыш в коде получается копеечный, но выходит что в целях микрооптимизаций (если вдруг дойдёт до них) предпочтительнее использовать новую конструкцию.

Comment: Это с включенными оптимизациями или без? linqPad просто и так, и так умеет

Comment: @rdorn я в подобных случаях проверяю, что оптимизации выключены, не забыл и сейчас. Отключено, отключено - можете сами проверить. Вон же отладочные nop'ы для брейков в коде видны.

Comment: Да, уже проверил. С включенной код идентичный. тогда действительно не понятно откуда эта разница...

Comment: Основные оптимизации все равно делает jit.  То,  что IL разный, еще не означает,  что на выходе получится разный нативный код.

Comment: `public int Current => expression();` может иметь только одну точку выхода. `public int Current { get { ... } }` может иметь несколько точек выхода (несколько операторов `return`), поэтому используется другой шаблон генерации кода. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450864

Comment: @PetSerAl Любопытно. Ответом?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще вопрос сам по себе достаточно бессмысленный.

Вы сравниваете результат компиляции в IL, явно указываете что собираете **с отключенной отптимизацией**

> я в подобных случаях проверяю, что оптимизации выключены, не забыл и сейчас. Отключено, отключено - можете сами проверить. Вон же отладочные nop'ы для брейков в коде видны.

но и при этом пытаетесь сравнить "оптимизированность" кода.

Т.е. вы явно запретили компилятору оптимизировать, и делаете из последствий вашего запрета вывод, что компилятор иногда выдает "неоптимизированный код" :)

Если хотите получить оптимизированный код - включите оптимизацию. Если хотите получить код с отладочными вставками - выключите оптимизацию.

Вот этот артефакт:

```
IL_0007:  stloc.0     
IL_0008:  br.s        IL_000A
IL_000A:  ldloc.0
```

позволяет вам поставить брекпойнт на закрывающую скобку в

```
get
{
    return _id;
}
```

В случае нескольких return в методе - вы, скорее всего, получите пачку безусловных переходов на одну и ту же метку:

```
get
{
    if (some)
    {
        return _id;
    }
    else
    {
        return 42;
    }
} // брекпойнт на этой строке срабатывает всегда!
```

IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldarg.0
IL_0002:  ldfld      bool ConsoleApp1.Abc::some
IL_0007:  stloc.0
IL_0008:  ldloc.0
IL_0009:  brfalse.s  IL_0015
IL_000b:  nop
IL_000c:  ldarg.0
IL_000d:  ldfld      int32 ConsoleApp1.Abc::_id
IL_0012:  stloc.1
IL_0013:  br.s       IL_001b
IL_0015:  nop
IL_0016:  ldc.i4.s   42
IL_0018:  stloc.1
IL_0019:  br.s       IL_001b
IL_001b:  ldloc.1
IL_001c:  ret
```

При отключенной отптимизации компилятор старается сделать код удобным для отладки, и, кроме nop-ов, вставляет вот такие вот костыли с явным сохранением возвращаемого значения в локальную переменную.

Включите оптимизацию - и отладочные хаки из IL исчезнут.

enSO:

- [Why is the 'br.s' IL opcode used in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323373/why-is-the-br-s-il-opcode-used-in-this-case)
- [Why does this very simple C# method produce such illogical CIL code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445864/why-does-this-very-simple-c-sharp-method-produce-such-illogical-cil-code/48450864#48450864)

Comment: Вот что nop'ы вставляются для отладки я знал, а про закрывающую скобку никогда не задумывался, что она тоже будет как-то иметь в IL отображение.